# Pipe two files to bash, and run remotely via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access

I want to send two files to bash and run remotely via ssh. I have the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Logging in..."
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my.pem user@x.x.x.x -T "bash -l" < ${MY_HOME}/check.sh
```

which works, but I have some variables in another I would like to make available inside check.sh remotely. Here's what I want in a broken way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Logging in..."
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my.pem user@x.x.x.x -T "bash -l" < (${MY_HOME}/vars.sh < ${MY_HOME}/check.sh)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? The above doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it--you just need to "cat" the files together.

```
cat ${MY_HOME}/vars.sh ${MY_HOME}/check.sh | ssh -i ~/.ssh/my.pem user@x.x.x.x -T "bash -l"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting an error "bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory" when I try this. Is it because it's creating the file locally, and bash is trying to resolve the temp/pseudo file remotely?

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk: yeah, sorry about that, I updated my answer, you can try it again.

Comment: Genius! Works perfectly now! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot! If've been looking for this.